# EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_format

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am working on Drupal 7.41. I recently updated around 100 modules for a client. Unfortunately some of the sites functionality broke updating one of the modules. I only did a backup before updating the modules and right after the 100 updates.

In one of the pages when trying to view it, I get the following error:

```
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_format. en EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (línea 335 de /var/www/abrepr.org/abrepr/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).
```

[image]

I have no idea how to fix this error. The rest of the site works flawlessly, it's just this one web page which doesn't even load. I've tried modifying the code of the file referenced but no success so far.

Anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

UPDATE1:

I tried downgrading the Entity and Entity API module back to the version before upgrading and still the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had similar issue. you can revert back to your old db backup. then you'll need to downgrade the following modules that might be the culprit:

- rules
- entity
- ctools
- context

downgrade them one at a time until your site works. it could be rules as that module usually breaks the site.

Comment: I will try downgrading the modules first without reverting to the old DB backup.... or do I need to revert to the old backup in order to get the downgraded modules to work properly?

Comment: The 'rules' module was the one causing all the issues. I removed it and everything seems to be working now.Thanks!